# Create Github hook to trigger Bamboo build

Tags: github, githooks, bamboo

I created a *Github Service hook* to trigger a build in *Bamboo*. This is the *Build Key* I entered in Github

```
master:GAUTR-UNIT
```

This only triggers the master branch. How can I trigger the other branches without manually entering each branch's name and *Bamboo Build Key* in *Github*

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Bamboo auto-detects creation of remote branches, and gives them names like `GAUTR-UNIT2` for a branch that might be named `develop`, and it sucks having to add every branch to the hook setup to have Bamboo properly test it.

Comment: Same issue here - when I commit to a branch, it builds the master, unless I specify the branch name in the GitHub service. Also, the name of the author which triggered the build is not preserved, all builds are triggered by the "github" user configured in the GitHub service. I'm switching back to polling!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to (in Bamboo 5) check off the "automatically manage branches" setting under your plan configuration, and bamboo will automatically pull and build the branches you specify with the regular express:

[image: example screenshot]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/26306e8536b52fa5c77a00a975fc798b.png))</sub>

Here you can see I'm building the master and development branch.

Hth,
Aaron